# how to change button background colour in tableview cell swift3

Tags: ios, swift3, uitableview

I have one `UITableViewCell`. In TableViewCell, I have 7 buttons in single row. I want to play music. When i press button1, its background colour should be changed. If I pressed button2, its background colour should be changed, and button1 would be deselect. I also set the tag for each button in row, but i don't understand, how to do? Sound is playing fine but i am unable to select and deselect buttons. I am using `swift3`. Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> tableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PlayerCell") as! tableViewCell

     cell.Btn_one.addTarget(self, action: #selector(TableViewController.BtnAction_One), for: .touchUpInside)

     //For example
       if (cell.Btn_one.tag == 1){

        cell.Btn_one.backgroundColor = .white
    }else if (cell.Btn_two.tag == 2){
               cell.Btn_two.backgroundColor = .red
    }
 }


 @IBAction func BtnAction_One(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.play()
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

@Chetan solution for this : first one

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellData", for: indexPath)

    let btn1 = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIButton
    let btn2 = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UIButton
    let btn3 = cell.viewWithTag(3) as! UIButton
    let btn4 = cell.viewWithTag(4) as! UIButton
    let btn5 = cell.viewWithTag(5) as! UIButton
    let btn6 = cell.viewWithTag(6) as! UIButton

    btn1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    btn2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    btn3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    btn4.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    btn5.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    btn6.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell
}
```

when this will to btnClicked 
`  func btnClickec(sender:UIButton){
      sender.isSelected = true

```
    let cell = sender.superview?.superview as! UITableViewCell

    let btn1 = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIButton
    let btn2 = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UIButton
    let btn3 = cell.viewWithTag(3) as! UIButton
    let btn4 = cell.viewWithTag(4) as! UIButton
    let btn5 = cell.viewWithTag(5) as! UIButton
    let btn6 = cell.viewWithTag(6) as! UIButton

    let arr = [btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4,btn5,btn6];

    for index in 0...5{
        let btn = arr[index]
        if index+1 == sender.tag{
            btn.isSelected = true
        }else{
            btn.isSelected = false
        }
    }
}
```

`

And second one : or you can collection view inside tableviewcell also

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it:

first the function:

```
func switchColor(isWhite: Bool, sender: UIButton) {
        if isWhite == true {
            sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControlState.normal)
        }else if isWhite == false {
            sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.clear, for: UIControlState.normal)
        }
```

Then where I call it:

```
@IBAction func RepeatWeeklyPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if sender.backgroundColor == UIColor.white {
            switchColor(isWhite: true, sender: sender)
        }else {
            switchColor(isWhite: false, sender: sender)
        }
    print("Pressed a repeat button")
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I suggest you to subclass from UIButton, like this:

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {

var isPressed = false

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

convenience init(frame: CGRect, title: String, tag: Int) {
    self.init(frame: frame)

    self.frame = frame
    setTitle(title, for: .normal)
    setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    switch tag {
        case 0: //Play a music
            if isPressed{
                backgroundColor = .black
            } else {
                backgroundColor = .clear
            }
        case 1: //Play a video
            if isPressed{
                backgroundColor = .black
            } else {
                backgroundColor = .clear
            }
    default: //Other
        if isPressed{
            backgroundColor = .black
        } else {
            backgroundColor = .clear
        }
    }

    if isPressed { isPressed = false } else { isPressed = true }
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

After that, in your cell I'd have some like...

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)

    let musicB = CustomButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0), title: "1", tag: 1)
    addSubview(musicB)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to subclass the button as CustomButton or whatever you would like to call it. And you'll need to create a delegate to let your viewcontroller know whats up.

Create a func that takes in an integer. This will be the code that'll take in your button's tag and preform some code. @Gabs had the right idea there.

```
func select(index: Int) {
  switch sender.tag {
        case 0: //do something
        case 1: //do something
        }
}
```

Create a single IBAction then link all your buttons to it. Inside, call the method created above

```
 @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
  select(index: sender.tag)
}
```

all that's missing is the viewController being informed on which button has been tapped. Set a delegate for it in your CustomCell view file and have it capture the sender.tag in your IBAction. Be sure to conform your viewcontroller too so the delegation works.